Getting "'Preload additional info' has encountered a problem. when opening a file in PyDev
Eclipse Platform:
Version: 2024-06 (4.32)
Build id: I20240601-0610
PyDev for Eclipse    12.2.0.202409031913
wxPython    4.2.2
wxFormBuilder    Version 4.2.1-0-g80c4cb6
#######
When I open a file in eclipse using PyDev, I get this error dialog:
Problem Occurred
'Preload additional info' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during "Preload additional info".
Details: An internal error occurred during "Preload additional info".
For input string: "11(1)"
########################################################
Sometimes I use PSPad to edit files, and the string "1:1(1)"appears on the status bar representing line 1 column 1.
If I click OK, everything worked fine as far as editing is concerned.
But when I try to execute the program, the bindings between the GUI events and the event handlers in the Python code
are scrambled.  The wrong handler is called.
Here is the error log entry for "An internal error occurred during: "Preload additional info"."
    eclipse.buildId=4.32.0.I20240601-0610
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

org.eclipse.core.jobs
Error
Mon Sep 23 12:55:42 EDT 2024
An internal error occurred during: "Preload additional info".

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11 (1)"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver$1.compare(DeltaSaver.java:232)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver$1.compare(DeltaSaver.java:1)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:360)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:179)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver.findDeltas(DeltaSaver.java:226)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver.loadDeltas(DeltaSaver.java:196)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver.<init>(DeltaSaver.java:174)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AbstractAdditionalInfoWithBuild.createDeltaSaver(AbstractAdditionalInfoWithBuild.java:109)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AbstractAdditionalInfoWithBuild.init(AbstractAdditionalInfoWithBuild.java:50)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.<init>(AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.java:114)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.getAdditionalInfoForProject(AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.java:246)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.getAdditionalInfoAndNature(AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.java:189)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.getAdditionalInfoAndNature(AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.java:160)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.getAdditionalInfo(AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.java:147)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.getAdditionalInfo(AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.java:137)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.builder.PreloadAdditionalInfoPyEditListener$1.run(PreloadAdditionalInfoPyEditListener.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

Here's the error log for "For input string: "16 (1)"
eclipse.buildId=4.32.0.I20240601-0610
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

org.python.pydev.shared_core
Error
Mon Sep 23 12:55:41 EDT 2024
For input string: "16 (1)"

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16 (1)"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver$1.compare(DeltaSaver.java:232)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver$1.compare(DeltaSaver.java:1)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:179)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver.findDeltas(DeltaSaver.java:226)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver.loadDeltas(DeltaSaver.java:196)
    at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver.<init>(DeltaSaver.java:174)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.ProjectModulesManager.setProject(ProjectModulesManager.java:75)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.ASTManager.setProject(ASTManager.java:54)
    at org.python.pydev.plugin.nature.PythonNature$RebuildPythonNatureModules.run(PythonNature.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)


Is this an eclipse problem, pydev problem, wxpython problem, etc?
From which file(s) does 'additional info' come?
How can I fix this?


Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

According to the log (line at org.python.pydev.core.DeltaSaver$1.compare(DeltaSaver.java:232) as the top most item not referring to the Java system library), it seems to be a PyDev issue: a string containing a number is expected, but in fact the string has the suffix (1), which does not seem to be expected, causing the issue. Please make sure that the issue has been reported to PyDev with a minimal reproducible example.

Thank you so much.  I'll report it right now.

The error occurs in this line of PyDev code. In your project, do you have a folder name or a file name containing (1)?

Thanks for the pointer.  I did a search from the file explorer of my project file.  I see files with '1' in them, but none with '(1)'.  Is there some other way I should search?  BTW, I added an issue to the PyDev issue tracker.  Again, thanks for all your help.

Thanks for reporting it to PyDev. As there are no files or folders containing (1), I'm not aware of anything you could try as a workaround. To track the issue down and to verify whether the issue is related to your data, you might try to close your project (by right-clicking your project folder and choosing Close Project) and check whether the issue persists. And if not, create a minimal project and copy the things one by one from your old project into the new project until the issue appears again.

If it's OK with you, I'd like to send the PyDev file and line# where the error occurs to them.

The new project idea is good.  I'll try that.  Thanks.

As you suggested, I tried a new project.  That didn't work.  I then tried a new workspace.  That worked.  Again, thanks for all your help.
